# jquery fade in and out saving data chunk

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm having some trouble with jQuery.

I have this code:

```
<div id="divSavingInformation" style="position:absolute;">All changes saved.</div>
$(function(){

        $(document).on("blur","div[contenteditable=true]",function() {

            var wait = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3000) + 500;

            $('#divSavingInformation').fadeOut(500, function() {
                $('#divSavingInformation').html("<i class='fa fa-spinner fa-pulse fa-lg fa-fw'></i> Saving data...").fadeIn(500).delay(5000).fadeOut(500).html("All data saved.").fadeIn(500);
            });

            var field_userid = $(this).attr("id") ;
            var value = $(this).text() ;
            $.post('pages/ajax/updateRadio.php' , field_userid + "=" + value, function(data){

            });
        });
    });
```

The code is triggered via a contenteditable div.
here is a jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/oyv27cce/3/

Which doesn't work the way I need it to.
Basically, what I need it to do is this:

1. Fade out div named "divSavingInformation"
2. Change content of div to `<i class='fa fa-spinner fa-pulse fa-lg fa-fw'></i> Saving data...`
3. fade in div to show the change above
4. wait some seconds while showing the div, this will be a variable later, for now I'm using 5 seconds.
5. fade div back out
6. Change contents of div to `All data saved`
7. fade back in and stay showing

Currently, what the code does is fade out and back in but the content doesn't appear to change. I think I am using delays wrong, maybe it is changing the content back to `All data saved` before it fades back in, making it look like the spinner is never shown.

I have no idea what I am doing, and could really use some help.

Comment: share your full code using jsbin or jsfiddle so that easier to help you

Comment: @SarathKumar Done.

Comment: wait editing...

Comment: try this https://jsfiddle.net/oyv27cce/4/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that `fadeIn()` and `fadeOut()` are asynchronous and they are queued up to perform the effect AFTER the currently running function completes. You will need to defer the final effect until after the function finishes and get rid of the `delay()` call as this will be taken care of by the `setTimout()`:

```js
$('#divSavingInformation').hide();
$('#divSavingInformation').html("<i class='fa fa-spinner fa-pulse fa-lg fa-fw'></i> Saving data...</div>").fadeIn(500).fadeOut(5000);;

// Defer the following code until after this function has completed.
setTimeout(function(){

  $('#divSavingInformation').html('All data saved.').fadeIn(500);
}, 5000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="divSavingInformation"></div>
```

Comment: @IAmGroot I Am Groot!

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use setTimeout() for this.

```js
var element = $('div');

element.fadeIn();

setTimeout(function(){
  element.fadeOut();
}, 2000);
```

This will fade in the element and fadeout after 2000ms or 2 seconds.

**You could use this:**

$.ajax({
    url: "/post/url.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: parameters,
    success: successFunction,
    error: errorFunction
});

And then by using the functions successFunction and errorFunction you can process these situations. You could expand your inline edit so when it fails, your user knows aswell. XEditable is a library which does just that.

Comment: The OP already has the element fading in and out. The issue is that the content doesn't change at the appropriate time.

Comment: I added a jsfiddle.

Comment: Why don't u use the success on the Ajax call to change to content, I guess that would be a realistic way of saying ' Data successfully added' when the AJAX call is successfull. Anyway, you content isn't changing at the right time as using the delay function in this way doesn't work. You should use the function I proposed which will solve a lot of headaches :)

Comment: @CirykPopeye I don't know how to use the success call.

Comment: Instead of using $.post you could use $.ajax, which would send an AJAX call to a page.